# MTurkR qualification xml read

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am following an example to add a qualifier to an MTurk survey using library MTurkR:
https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/wiki/Qualification-Tests-for-Worker-Pre-Screening

reading the xml external files (for example):

```
QuestionForm <- paste0(readLines('Test.xml'), collapse='')
```

generates the warning message:

```
In readLines("Test.xml") :   incomplete final line found on 'Test.xml'
```

The contents of Question form are a bit unwieldy to paste (the file is below), but the final line is the example closing .

The warning appears important when I try to build the Qualification with this command:

```
newqual <- CreateQualificationType(name="Qualification",
                                   description="A qualification for our HITs",
                                   status="Active", test.duration=seconds(hours=1),
                                   test=QuestionForm, answerkey = AnswerKey)
```

which generates these errors:

> AttValue: " or ' expected attributes construct error Couldn't find end
>   of Start Tag QuestionForm line 1 Extra content at the end of the
>   document Error: 1: AttValue: " or ' expected 2: attributes construct
>   error 3: Couldn't find end of Start Tag QuestionForm line 1 4: Extra
>   content at the end of the document

Test.xml is pasted below. I tried adding a blank end line per some online suggestions elsewhere, then made sure no spaces or blank lines were present. I am getting the same error for the AnswerKey.xml. The LayoutID generated on the site works well for questionnaire creation/data dump/administration, but this is the sticking point.

Test.xml:

```
<QuestionForm xmlns=<"http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurk 
DataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd">
<Overview>
    <Title>Qualify for the job HIT</Title>
    <Text>
      Please answer one question to see if you qualify (automatically scored)
    </Text>
</Overview>
  <Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>employ</QuestionIdentifier>
    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
    <QuestionContent>
      <Text>Which best describes your current work?</Text>
    </QuestionContent>
    <AnswerSpecification>
      <SelectionAnswer>
        <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
        <Selections>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>1</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Employed (full- or part-time) for pay and not looking for work</Text>
          </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>2</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Not employed for pay and NOT looking for work (e.g., stay-at-home parent)</Text>
          </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>3</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Looking for work (whether employed, part-time employed, or unemployed)</Text>
          </Selection>
        </Selections>
      </SelectionAnswer>
    </AnswerSpecification>
  </Question>
</QuestionForm>
```

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/108654.html
suggests that the readLines command is not a problem and the warning can just be shut off

Comment: Problem solved:
I believed that I could set the inclusion criteria using a later GenerateQualificationRequirement, so I had removed the text below from AnswerKey.xml. It turns out it was necessary.
 `<QualificationValueMapping>
<PercentageMapping>
<MaximumSummedScore>1</MaximumSummedScore></PercentageMapping>
</QualificationValueMapping>`